# Whats the difference when add `[ ]` to regular expressions?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I watch a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGqNdBJH4xk&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTOcOVdZF-th7BS_GYGguAS&index=7), in the 2:13 second, there is a urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'), 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w+])/edit/$', PostUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w+])/delete/$', PostDeleteAPIView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

We know we can use `\d+` to match the numbers, use `\w+` to match character,number,and `_`.

But why in there the `\w+` be wrap with `[]`? can do not wrap it?

And by the way, many Django model use a slug field, why use it? and the slug field has what function? whats the deep meaning of slug?

Comment: Slugs help keep your urls human-readable: instead of an id-based `'example.com/blog/34'` you could have `'example.com/blog/my-day-out'`

Comment: @schwobaseggl So, the slug should be unique, alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[\w+]` actually matches either any word character `\w` or `+`, the plus character.  Take a look at the explanation tab of this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/eIctY0/1